# Import a python property in other file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, aws-cdk

py like this

```
class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str,  **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        my_api = _apigateway.LambdaRestApi(
            scope=self,
            proxy=False
        )
```

I want to get this my_api property in 2nd file I am trying something like this

**from .file1 import my_api**

but getting error of **ImportError: cannot import name**

Answer (score 1):

You define a class here. Then in your other module you will want to import the module containing the class, and instanciate it.

```py
import ma_lib
[some code that creates a my_app object that is CDK app]
my_stack = MyStack(my_app, "Name")
my_api = my_stack.my_api
```

Comment: thanks sir for reply there are two confusions , 1st  what is this for   `import ma_lib`  and 2nd   `MyStack(None, "Name")` what is name here ?

Comment: `import ma_lib` is what you would put if `MyStack` is in a file name `ma_lib` at the same root.

Comment: In CDK, you have two mandatory arguments, the scope and the id. Here I supposed you could put no scope and this would work. But you should probably send the app itself instead. And for the id, I put `Name` but you could replace by whatever you want. Indeed I would even say "you should replace by whatever will be more explicit as a stack name for you. »

Comment: getting this error   :   jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot reference across apps. Consuming and producing stacks must be defined within the same CDK app.

Comment: Ok then it means that you should send not `None` but your app.

Comment: sent app but still same error